# Batch path variable with space - how to escape the double quotes?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I'm setting a variable with this directory

```
C:\My dir\Sub dir\Folder with a lot of spaces\file.html
```

like this:

```
SET location="C:\My dir\Sub dir\Folder with a lot of spaces\file.html"
```

The problem is, when I echo `%location%` it comes with both double quotes. I've tried to remove using this:

```
set location=%location:"=\"%
```

But it does not work. I've searched a lot and I can't find an easy and simple solution. I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: Can you give some context for how you're using `location`? On the command line? In a batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy and simple solution is to store the path without the quotes, like this:

```
SET "location=C:\My dir\Sub dir\Folder with a lot of spaces\file.html"
```

This way the value will be stored with no quotes and the SET statement will still be protected from the effect of certain special characters. You will then either enclose `%location%` in quotes or omit the quotes as required. For instance, if you are using the value as an argument of some command, you will likely need to put the quotes around it:

```
somecommand "%location%" …
…
```

And if you just need to output the path, the quotes may be unnecessary – and it's easy to leave them out:

```
ECHO Location: %location%
…
```

Note that if the path has characters with special meaning, like `&`, ECHOing the path without the quotes would cause such characters to be interpreted in `%` evaluation. To avoid that, you could temporarily enable and use delayed expansion:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Location: !location!
ENDLOCAL
…
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `set "location=C:\My dir\Sub dir\Folder with a lot of spaces\file.html"` to keep the spaces but leave out the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quotes in `Set`.

Later when you use that variable you include quotes around it eg

```
type "%location%"
```

Also this removes quotes

```
set location=%location:"=%
```

Yours I think replaces quotes with a backslash and a quote, not very useful.

Why even put it into a variable?